# When/Where is a PublishProfile included in MSBUILD?

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

We are using MSBUILD for ClickOnce publishing. Since dotnet publish is not able to do see: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/69, we are using MSBUILD

```
msbuild /target:publish /p:PublishProfile="ClickOnceProfile.pubxml"
```

In our `Directory.Build.props` we have set several parameters (`PublishReadyToRun` etc.) that we want to have for every publish. Additionally, we want to have the `AssemblyFileVersion` in `ApplicationVersion` and I thought simply setting

```
<ApplicationVersion>$(AssemblyFileVersion)</ApplicationVersion>
```

would do the trick, but it doesn't. When looking into the binlog, it seems that the publish profile is the first in the row and then comes `Directory.Build.props` and `Directory.Build.targets`. However I couldn't see the includes in the timeline.

Does anyone know when the publish profile is included in the different MSBUILD stages?

Comment: Run msbuild with the /preprocess switch. The output will show the imports. If by "stages" you mean "phases", imports are performed in the evaluation phase. There is one evaluation phase for the project. See "[How MSBuild builds projects - Evaluation phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022#evaluation-phase)".

Comment: @JonathanDodds: Thanks for the info. I knew about /preprocess but I forgot because I'm not doing this often. Thanks for reminding me.